# Regex Matching numbers with floating point in javaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, floating-point

Here is the `pattern` on which i'm Working :

`/^\d+((.\d+))?(,\d+((.\d+))?)*$/`

Its supports

`1.2,30.5,13.54`

`25.65`

But i want the `pattern` which supports following:

`1.3,.3,4.5`

`.3,.4,.6`

`.2`

`1.3,5.6,.5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your given examples, you require a decimal part, so you could use

```
/(\d*\.\d+),?/
```

This will match every given example.
In case you also want to match numbers without a decimal dot, just add a second match:

```
/(\d*\.\d+|\d+),?/
```

Oh, and for JavaScript, to add the "g" modifier (for global search), you need to add it as a second parameter to the RegExp constructor:

```
re = new RegExp("(\d*\.\d+|\d+),?", "g");
```

Example: http://regex101.com/r/vL5aT0

Okay, I don't know on what purpose you are matching your strings. If you just want to validate them and they should exactly look like in your examples, use this:

```
/((\d*\.\d+|\d+),?)*(\d*\.\d+|\d+)$/
```

Thanks to Elergy for pointing me to this.
By the way, Elergy's regex also matches useless lines of only periods and commas, like

```
.3,.4,.5,,,,8,.,7.,.,.,.,4.,.,.,.,.9,.,,,4.,,1,,
```

Comment: Note you can also add the `g` flag by doing `/regex/g`.

Comment: Didn't knew that. Always thought, I need this blown up constructor for RegEx in JavaScript. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
/(\d+)?\.\d+(,?)/
```

`(\d+)?` Match all digits but optional.
`\d+(,?)` Match all digits with a `,` as optional.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of your problem is right, this expression can help you:

```
/^\d*[\.,]\d*(?:,\d*[\.,]\d*)*$/
```

Comment: If we entered single digit expression will fail.
like `3`.

For all other input it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do with them afterwards? If you goal is to identify a comma separated list of valid floating point numbers, you can use the `Number` constructor, which returns `NaN` if the number is invalid (which evaluates to `false`):

```
"1.3,5.6,a.s".split(",").every(Number)
false
"1.3,5.6,.5".split(",").every(Number)
true
```

Personally I like to avoid regex where possible and I think that this is pretty self-documenting. `split` the string on `,` and check that [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) value is a valid number.